Next.js 14 Image sizing
I had a number of images rendered in my Next.js app like so :
{projects.map((project, i) => {
            return (
              <Image
                key={i}
                src={`/images/${project.src}`}
                alt={project.title}
                width="0"
                height="0"
                sizes="300px"
                style={{ width: "300px", height: "auto" }}
                unoptimized
              />
            );
          })}

but i get this error for every image even though height is set to auto
Image with src "/images/portfolio-website.jpg" has either width or height modified, but not the other. If you use CSS to change the size of your image, also include the styles 'width: "auto"' or 'height: "auto"' to maintain the aspect ratio.


Make width: auto

But I wanted the image to take up the whole width of its parent

then use the fill attribute, don't use manual width and height
